# Akka Http API singleton user context

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am writing a REST API using Scala and Akka Http.

For request handling, I implement Routes in the form of `RequestContext => Future[RouteResult]`

In each route, I have to pass the context of the user from function to function, which becomes a bit cumbersome.  For example, in the code below, I always have to pass `userContext` into every function that interacts with the DB.

```
val route: Route = {    
   requestContext => {
      val userContext = extractUser(requestContext)
      val computeResult = compute(userContext)
      requestContext.complete(computeResult)   
   } 
}
```

However, if I set the context to a singleton, then it runs the risk of being overridden when the next calls comes in, since the API is multi-tenant.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: added some sample code

Comment: You could make the context implicit, but I personally don't find your code to be bad

Comment: Yeah the `compute` function has many layers, and each one requires the `userContext` to be passed in.  I like the idea of implicit though.

Answer (score 0):

Give an opportunity to Reader Monad. That will allow you a better abstraction over your UserContext.

This could be an aprox:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import scalaz.{Reader, ReaderT}

trait UserContext {
  val user: String
  val passwd: String
}

trait YourDBFunctionsII[T] {
  def compute(): Reader[UserContext, T]
  def computeII(): Reader[UserContext, T]
}

object YourDBFunctionsII extends YourDBFunctionsII[String] {
  override def compute(): Reader[UserContext, String] = Reader {
    in: UserContext =>
      ???
  }

  override def computeII(): Reader[UserContext, String] = Reader {
    in: UserContext =>
      ???
  }
}

class YourRoutesII {
  import YourDBFunctionsII._

  val route: Route = { requestContext =>
    {
      val userContext: UserContext = ??? // Extract from RequestContext

      val routines = for {
        resul1 <- compute()
        resul2 <- computeII()
      } yield resul2

      // Execute monad composition
      val computeResult = routines.run(userContext)

      requestContext.complete(computeResult)
    }
  }
}
```

If you need to deal with an asynchronous database driver you can use ScalaZ ReaderT type:

```
trait YourDBFunctionsIII[T] {
  def compute(): ReaderT[Future, UserContext, T]
  def computeII(): ReaderT[Future, UserContext, T]
}

// In case you want to deal with Futures
object YourDBFunctionsIII extends YourDBFunctionsIII[String] {

  override def compute(): ReaderT[Future, UserContext, String] = ReaderT {
    ctx =>
      Future {
        // Do something
        ctx.passwd
      }.recover {
        case e: Throwable =>
          "Error"
      }
  }

  override def computeII(): ReaderT[Future, UserContext, String] = ReaderT {
    ctx =>
      Future {
        // Do other thing
        ctx.passwd
      }
  }
}

class YourRoutesIII {
  import YourDBFunctionsIII._

  val route: Route = { requestContext =>
    {
      val userContext: UserContext = ??? // Extract from RequestContext

      val routines = for {
        resul1 <- compute()
        resul2 <- computeII()
      } yield resul2

      // Execute monad composition
      val computeResult = routines.run(userContext)

      requestContext.complete(computeResult)
    }
  }
}
```

In both cases you only need to run the monad composition with the UserContext instance.